# Property of Markov chains

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, markov-chains

Let $(X_k)_{k\in \mathbb{Z}_{+}}$ be a Markov chain with state space $I$ and let $J_0,J_1, \ldots,J_{n+1}$ be subsets of $I$. Prove that:

$$\mathbb{P}(X_{n+1} \in J_{n+1} | X_n \in J_n,\cdots,X_0 \in J_0) = \mathbb{P}(X_{n+1} \in J_{n+1} | X_n \in J_n) $$

I was thinking of using the Markov property to be able to take it to each element of $J_{n+1}$ but I have not been able to prove anything.

Comment: It seems that the state space is implicitly assumed to be a subset of the nonnegative integers.

Comment: Anyway, assuming the state space is the set of nonnegative integers, are you sure this equality is true?

Comment: Oh sorry the state space is $I$ and $J_k \subseteq I$.

Comment: If $J_n$ consists of more than one point, this is actually not true.

Comment: Could you give a counterexample? at first glance it might appear to be true.

Answer (score 1):

For a simple counterexample just take almost any situation where there are multiple states, $J_n$ is the entire space, and $J_{n+1}$ is not the entire space.

For example $I=\{ 0,1 \},J_0=\{ 0 \},J_1=\{ 0,1 \},J_2 = \{ 0 \}$, the transition matrix is just the identity, and the initial distribution in the right hand side is uniformly distributed on both states. Then on the right side, assuming $X_1 \in J_1$ adds nothing, so $P(X_2 \in J_2 \mid X_1 \in J_1)=P(X_2=0)=1/2$. Meanwhile on the left side, assuming $X_0 \in J_0$ does tell you something: $P(X_2 \in J_2 \mid X_1 \in J_1,X_0 \in J_0)=P(X_2=0 \mid X_0=0)=1$.

The point is that the Markov property says that if you know *exactly* where the particle is at time $n$, then it doesn't matter how it got there. But if you only have an *idea* of where it is at time $n$, then knowing something about how it got there may give you a better idea of where it actually is at time $n$, which is what determines its distribution in the future.

Comment: I don't understand your counterexample very well, could you elaborate a little better? thank you very much!

Comment: @JuanDanielValdiviaFuentes Let me know if this helps.

Comment: I got it, thank you very much!